# JS1015: Unterminated string constant 。

Tags: javascript, special-characters

Getting JS1015: Unterminated string constant error in IE and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in Chrome with the following js code in case character  。

```
var smsDataList = ${requestScope.smsDataList};
```

`${requestScope.smsDataList}` contains the json string inside which  。 is present.

Any solution to support all types of characters?
Please note that this error is coming only in case of  。 and not because of any unclosed quotes.

Comment: Unterminated string constant error is usually a problem with nested quotes. (or simply missing close quotes)

Comment: Your best solution is to use the unicode escape sequences to represent characters not standardized in all character sets. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: @KevinBoucher yes it is correct, but i have verified, this problem is coming only with 

Comment: You'd need to escape it. Unicode escape sequences are both supported in JS and JSON